# If $M_1, M_2, M_3$ are symmetric, the matrices of the span $\{M_1, M_2, M_3\}$ will be symmetric too.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Well... as in the title. I'm just curious if this is a fact or something that needs to be proven?
I was reading a book and they out of no where said this so I'm quite confused here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M\in\text{span}\{M_1,M_2,M_3\}$. Then $M=c_1M_1+c_2M_2+c_3M_3$ for some scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$.

Since taking the transpose is linear, we have

$$M^T = (c_1M_1+c_2M_2+c_3M_3)^T = c_1M_1^T+c_2M_2^T+c_3M_3^T=c_1M_1+c_2M_2+c_3M_3 = M,$$
where the second last equality follows, since all of $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$ are symmetric.

Comment: thanks for that man. Just one question. what do you mean why "taking the transpose is linear"?

Comment: @Danxe I mean that you can consider the transpose as a map from the set of $n\times n$ matrices $M(n)$ to itself. As a map $M(n)\to M(n)$ that sends the matrix $A$ to $A^T$, the transpose is linear.

Comment: ohh.. ok thanks for that clear explanation!